# Du bist ein/en Junge

Tags: grammatical-case, nominative

Which sentence is grammatically correct and why?
Du bist einen Junge
Du bist einen Junge

I think its the second one, bit if it isn't then why is it not in the accusative tense?

Comment: If you write A = B, then A and B are equal (from some perspective). Hence, if you write "Du bis ein Junge", then "Du" = "ein Junge". This again means that both "Du" and "ein Junge" play the same role within the sentence. Thus you need nominative in both cases.

Comment: @Ronald - This is confusing for English speakers since English requires the objective case after "to be" (at least for most speakers). The logic that A and B "play the same role" does not work for English. To me, the best way to remember is JFK's famous line *Ich bin ein Berliner.*